# Deploying Google app engine with python failed

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, deployment

I try to deploy some files on google CDN (appspot) with Google App Engine release 1.19.7 and Python 2.7.9.
I'm sure that's it's not a big problem but I'm not a specialist.
I've created the application in 'Google developers'
The content of the file app.yaml is :

```
application: o-naturel  version: 1 runtime: python27 api_version: 1 threadsafe: true

# Expiration des fichiers : 30 jours default_expiration: "30d"

handlers:
- url: /styles   static_dir: styles

- url: /images   static_dir: images

- url: /files   static_dir: files

#- url: /.*
#  static_files: index.html
#  upload: index.html
```

Find below the errors during the deployment. Hope I will get an answer because I can not follow the development of my web site. Many thanks in advance !!!!

```
2014-12-12 17:56:28 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=patrick.sanchez24@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'D:\\Cdn-App_o-naturel']"
05:56 PM Application: o-naturel; version: 1
05:56 PM Host: appengine.google.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 127, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 123, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5397, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5388, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2978, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5044, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3791, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3812, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    updatecheck.CheckForUpdates()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\sdk_update_checker.py", line 243, in CheckForUpdates
    runtime=runtime))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 424, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
TypeError: do_open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
2014-12-12 17:56:31 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

Comment: There appear to be missing lots of newlines in the app.yaml as you posted it -- perhaps a Windows-newlines issue?  Not sure what problems that might cause (I don't do Windows:-) but can you see if you can get app.yaml (with some good editor?) into a state in which it will at least copy-and-paste correctly to here, and try again...?

Comment: The user 'Japanish' gave me the answer. It was a problem with Python 2.7.9. I used Python 2.7.8 and it worked perfectly. Thanks for anwering to my problem...

Comment: Related Google Issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11537

Answer (score 15):

If you use Python **2.7.9**, you should install Python **2.7.8**.
When I ran GAE/P in Python **2.7.9**, this error occured just like you.
However, it worked correctly, when I ran GAE/P in Python **2.7.8**.
Probably, the difference is between Python **2.7.9** released 2014-12-10 and GAE/P released 2014-12-8 now.

Please try Python **2.7.8**.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a bug in the SDK.
See Deep's link above.
for me simplest solution was to add:
`--skip_sdk_update_check=yes` to the additional options.
Later I will check for and download a newer version manually, and then remove the option again.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to continue using Python 2.7.9, the solution as shown in:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11536 worked for me.

Had to change three lines of code and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed for me by upgrading Google App Engine SDK to 1.9.18 (in GoogleAppEngineLauncher UI use Help > Check for updates).
I'm running Python 2.7.9.