# Error downloading App Engine source code with appcfg.py

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I try to download my code from google using:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A "canada-math"  ./trunk3
```

I have the old appengine installed under my home dir, which you can see in the error output below.

```
appcfg.py download_app -A "canada-math"  ./trunk3
```

I get this:

```
stephen@stephen-AO725:~/webprog$ appcfg.py download_app -A "canada-math"  ./trunk3

05:06 PM Host: appengine.google.com
05:06 PM Fetching file list...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stephen/webprog/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 171, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/home/stephen/webprog/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 167, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/stephen/webprog/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4282, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/home/stephen/webprog/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4273, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "/home/stephen/webprog/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2409, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/home/stephen/webprog/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4003, in __call__
    return method()
  File "/home/stephen/webprog/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2861, in DownloadApp
    DoDownloadApp(rpcserver, out_dir, app_id, module, app_version)
  File "/home/stephen/webprog/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1373, in DoDownloadApp
    result = rpcserver.Send('/api/files/list', **url_args)
  File "/home/stephen/webprog/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
TypeError: do_open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is likely to download the source code by running `appcfg.py` in [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-cloud-shell). That will ensure that your appcfg.py and Python versions are compatible with the App Engine API.

Depending on your specific versions of appcfg and Python, you may have a version mismatch. Also keep in mind that [appcfg is deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appcfg-arguments). See also:

- [SDK is incompatible with python 2.7.9](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35898585)
- [Deploying Google app engine with python failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453497/deploying-google-app-engine-with-python-failed)

Comment: I was able to download the files in the cloudshell. now how do I download from the shell? it's in a folder called trunk3. No error on running the same line as before, so it must be compatibility issues, very good guess from you.